# How to connect my domain to my windows server

Tags: domain-name-system, iis

I have domain purchased on mochahost and they registered ns1.mydomainname.com which points to ip address of my server. Then I used that ns on domain ns configuration. On IIS (on my server) I made new demo page with hostname mydomainname.com and port 80. I can see it when I enter public ip address, but I cannot see it when I enter mydomainname.com. On https://dnschecker.org/ I tested NS for mydomainname.com and only 6 are passing, all other fails. It is now one week since I set it all up. It should show after 48 hours, but I still cannot access it. Is there anything else that I forgot to set?

Comment: "I cannot see it when I enter mydomainname.com". If you want `http://mydomainname.com` to work, you must configure the raw domain name to point to the public IP address of your server, not any other DNS items (and unless you use a really bad DNS service, you never need 48 hours to know that you configured something the wrong way). Most domain name service providers have technical support, which is the best resource to guide you.

Comment: If you are having DNS problems, you should add your real domain name to the question. It will help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: real domain name is teradrops.com

Comment: Your nameserver is not responding (ns1.teradrops.com). You can use this tool to help with the diagnostic: https://intodns.com/teradrops.com

Comment: nameservers are pointing to proper ip address, but when I use my domain it does not access my server. I can't figure out what is wrong using this tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the role of a Name Server (NS).

The name server of your domain should not point towards the web server hosting your website (in theory the same server can host both roles -web server and name server- but it's not recommended).

A name server stores informations about the domains for which it is authoritative. The name server for your domain will give informations to the clients that (for example) "www.teradrops.com" is hosted on the server at IP "x.x.x.x." and "blog.teradrops.com" is on server "y.y.y.y".

Usualy, you don't have to setup you own Name Servers because this is a service provided by your registrar.

Since you provided the real domain name in the comments, whois shows us that your registrar is "enom.com", [they provide an explanation of what is a name server](https://help.enom.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000486451-Nameservers-NS-#what).

Here are some interesting part, from their website:

> Nameservers usually hold DNS records for thousands of domains. Each
>   domain usually have one or two A records that specify where the
>   website is being served from.

---

> Suppose someone wants to visit the website adamrocks.live.  Their
>   computer would [...] ask *the registrar* which nameservers are the correct nameservers for
>   this domain.  *The registrar* replies with the name server
>   dns1.name-services.com.  The computer then goes to
>   dns1.name-services.com and ask for the A record.
>   dns1.name-services.com looks at the DNS records it has stored and find
>   the A record 162.88.61.23.  The computer then goes to 162.88.61.23 and
>   ask for the HTML files and images that makes up the website.

---

> Enom provides free nameservers to use [...]

So, like many other registrars, they indeed provide name servers. I want to emphasize that this is not a way of operating specific to this registrar.

You should re-configure your domain to use their name servers instead of your non-responding name server, and manage the DNS records from their control panel (i.e: Creating an "A" record for "www" pointing towards the IP of your webserver for example).

I think that your IIS config is working because you said that with the public IP, your website shows up.

Additionally, if you want to host multiple websites under differents domains names on the same IIS Server, you can fill the "Host name" field in your bindings, so that IIS knows how to "differentiate" the websites:
[image: Bindings on IIS, hostname]

Comment: Thanks, I copy pasted what you wrote to customer service and in fourth conversation they figured out how to fix it. It is working now.